# How do i get JavaScript to run on chrome without extension

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, bots

I need help writing a code that can basically run a javascript code in a newly generated incognito window. My current code works with a google extension but I'm trying to make it a part of a bigger software that makes a chrome window in the background, goes on a site such as supreme, and runs code that clicks buttons to add an item to cart and checkout. I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to coding and such within chrome so any help would be appreciated :)

```
var i;
var atc_delay = "5000";
var category = "shirts";
var item_name = "Tartan Flannel Shirt";
var color = "Green";
var size = "Large";
var full_name = "Botter Boy";
var email = "botterboy@gmail.com";
var phone = "9096939163";
var address = "123 bot street";
var address2 = "apt 3311";
var zip = "92407";
var city = "cookout";
var state = "CA";
var country = "USA";
var credit = "credit card";
var creditnumber = "12345678910";
var month = "03";
var year ="2022";
var cvv = 123;


if(url == "https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all") {
    pickCategory();
}

else if(url != "https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all") {
    pickItem();
}


function pickCategory() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('category', function(data){
        var redirect = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets";
        var replace = redirect.replace("jackets", category);
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect:replace});
    });
}

function pickItem() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('item_name', function(data) {
        var items = document.getElementsByClassName('name-link')

        for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if((items[i].innerHTML).includes(color)) {
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: items[i].href});  
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}

function pickColor() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('color', function(data) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(color)[0].click();
    }
    )};
    




document.getElementById("order_billing_name").value = full_name;
document.getElementById("order_email").value = email;
document.getElementById("order_tel").value = phone;
document.getElementById("bo").value = address;
document.getElementById("oba3").value = address2;
document.getElementById("order_billing_zip").value = zip;
document.getElementById("order_billing_city").value = city;
document.getElementById("order_billing_state").value = state;
document.getElementById("order_billing_country").value = country;
document.getElementById("credit_card_type").value = credit;
document.getElementById("rnsnckrn").value = creditnumber;
document.getElementById("credit_card_month").value = month;
document.getElementById("credit_card_year").value = year;
document.getElementById("orcer").value = cvv;
document.getElementsByName("store_address")[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName("iCheck-helper")[1].click();
document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].click();
```

Comment: @markspace my b. its javascript. I just updated it and provided the code

Comment: Which google extension? You can execute js through python or java with selenium.

Comment: @Yun My own google extension that runs the code. wdym